# Using mod_rewrite to rewrite the URL making it more user and seo friendly

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Im looking to rewrite my URL so it is more SEO and user friendly, I have spend a lot of time on this and am struggling to get my head around how the rewrite process works.

One of the issues I'm having is that my Site is broken up in sections using sub domains, The site is a comparison site that will allow you to find details on a product or compare the product against another. The cameras section is under 'cameras.specced.co.uk' and there will be other sections I will make in the future such as 'drones.specced.co.uk' and 'phones.specced.co.uk'.

Currently I load page information via numeric ID's for example, this is the URL that fetches all specifications for the Canon 1300D:

```
http://cameras.specced.co.uk/compare.php?i=98
```

I would like to rewrite this into something like this

```
http://cameras.specced.co.uk/compare/98
```

For the pages that compare 2 products side by side, the URL currently looks like this, (URL fetches comparison of Canon 1300D VS Nikon D5300)

```
http://cameras.specced.co.uk/compare.php?1=98&2=111
```

I would like to rewrite this URL into something like this

```
http://cameras.specced.co.uk/compare/98-vs-111
```

This is what I have come up with, however does not work

```
RewriteRule    ^i/([0-9]+)/?$    compare.php?i=$1    [NC,L]    # Handle product requests
```

I greatly appreciate any help

Comment: Looks all fine, but what is your actual question? There are _millions_ of examples alone here on SO for exactly what you ask, certainly one of those answers would help? And if not, since you ask again, what difference would another answer make?

Comment: Im hoping someone can help me rewrite my URL using mod_rewrite, I have tried and failed at this multiple times and have some here as I am now really stuck. I would like to rewrite this URL: http://cameras.specced.co.uk/compare.php?i=98 into something like this: http://cameras.specced.co.uk/compare/98

Comment: That is pretty straight forward. If you have issues doing so then please add the code you currently have to your question and explain what _exactly_ is wrong with it, so what _exactly_ happens if you use it.

Comment: Seems like `compare/(\d+)` might be a starting point, you'll need a rule before that for the `vs` and to stop at that rule.

Comment: I have deleted the code as none of it works, would you mind just giving me an example of how you would rewrite this url as you say it is straight forward and I'm very stuck, I would then see how I can adapt this to my other URL's

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for something like that: two rules, typically first the more specialized:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?compare/(\d+)-vs-(\d+)$ /compare.php?i1=$1&i2=$2 [END]
RewriteRule ^/?compare/(\d+)$ /compare.php?i=$1 [END]
```

Those rules will work in both, dynamic configuration files (".htaccess") and in the real http servers host configuration. If you decide to use dynamic configuration files then you need to take care to actually enable their interpretation first. Take a look at the `AllowOverride` directive for that: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride

If you are using a really old version of the apache http server then you may have to replace the `[END]` flag with the `[L]` flag. You will then get an internal server error otherwise and find according hints in the http servers error log file.

A general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers (virtual) host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (`.htaccess` style files). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Hmmm never heard it was better to include the rules at the configuration level. For a new rewrite rule though that'd require restarting the apache instance, no?

Comment: @chris85 Indeed that is a detail rarely pointed out, although it is even part of the official documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html The reason is obvious: performance, maintainability and security.

Comment: @chris85 Yes, a change in the host configuration requires a restart of the server. However that can be done using the "graceful" strategy, so without any interruption of service.

Comment: @arkascha Thankyou very much for your answer and showing how I can rewrite these 2 URL's... I have created a .htaccess in the root folder and pasted your code into it, and just incase created another .htaccess in the subdomain root folder however there seems to be no change and after refreshing all URL's in browser they still have not changed to the new URL layout... (I'm with GoDaddy if that makes a difference) Thanks

Comment: @cousbrad No really sure what you mean by "still have not changed to the new URL layout"... just to be sure, since many people miss understand how rewriting works: if you request `/compare/12345`, what _exactly_ happens then? And are you really sure (really?) that you have actually enabled the interpretation of dynamic configuration files? Check that by placing a definite syntax error in such file. What happens then?

Comment: @arkascha Hello, i didn't realise I would need to change the <a href> links for the new URL structure, One issue I found is if I enter the url as : http://cameras.specced.co.uk/compare/232 then all the images disappear on the page ? please could you have a look at my website to see what I mean  Thank you again,

Comment: @cousbrad Certainly server internal rewriting on _incoming_ requests cannot somehow magically modify URLs coded in html documents somewhere else. But don't worry, that is a common miss conception. Happens :-) Indeed internal rewriting only works on the URL specified in incoming requests. How those were triggered is completely out of control of that step.

Comment: @arkascha thank you for understanding, :D, I have not been doing well with the URL rewrite stuff so greatly appreciate your help, Im guessing the rewritten URL means I can only retrieve images stored on the subdomain and not in the root directory ? because the image of the camera in the link I send you shows (stored in subdomain folder) and the logo and other icons do not (stored in root directory)

Comment: @cousbrad About the disappearing images: this is due to the fact that you use relative links in your html markup, so for example `images/icons/image.png`. such relative links are interpreted by browsers as relative to the path the containing html page was loaded from, so here `/compare/images/icons/image.png`. But that is not where the image is located. Three options: use absolute references (`/images/icons/image.png`), use correct relative references (`../icons/image.png`) or define additional rewrite rules for such assets.

Comment: @cousbrad I am not sure what you refer to with the expression "subdomain". All your examples show only a single domain you use (actually a host name would be the technically correct label). People mentioning "subdomains" typically refer to something like `api.example.org` an extension to `example.org`, but that is nothing I can see in your case.

Comment: @arkascha I understand, Thanks for that, should be able to get that fixed up this morning thanks to your help... (last question haha) slightly off topic, would you say to improve SEO I should output the product name in the URL also, /compare/99/canon_100d where the '99' is the only useful part and the product name is there just for SEO purposes ?

Comment: @cousbrad Sorry, I am not an SEO guy, but I doubt that the rules relevant for SEO optimization are actually that well known (they are kept secret by the search engines) or stable enough (they change over time) that a definite answer is possible for this. Most people appear to use both, the technical ID and some twisted product name, but I do not really expect that to make a real difference.

Comment: @arkascha My main domain is specced.co.uk however I have different sub domains for the sections of electronics, so cameras.specced.co.uk, I will make drones.specced.co.uk and phones.specced.co.uk once I have made cameras.specced.co.uk first

Comment: @cousbrad Ok, sounds fine. For those "broken" images on your site: question is if you can reach the images via that subdomain which you definitely should take care of to prevent issues with cross domain requests. If you want to share an image folder between all subdomains you use (for example for icons), then do _not_ place them inside any document root, but in a shared folder outside the normal document tree and configure an `Alias` pointing there: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#alias